# How are statements with uninitialized signals executed on very first EVENT?

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL [Dataflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dataflow_programming) modeling, all the statements are concurrent for each event.

For example, the event where `B` is first triggered leads to concurrent executions of statements **1**, **3**, and **6**. But in statement **6** we don't have value for `ABAR`.

So, will execution proceed with an initial (default) value of `ABAR` ([default to the leftmost value ('left) of its declared type](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~jmoorkan/vhdlref/sig_dec.html)), or what?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity DECODER2x4 is
port (A, B, ENABLE: in BIT;
     Z: out BIT_VECTOR(0 to 3));
end DECODER2x4; 

architecture dec_dataflgw of DECODER2x4 is
signal ABAR, BBAR: BIT;
begin
Z(3) <= not (A and B and ENABLE); --  statement 1
Z(0) <= not (ABAR and BBAR and ENABLE); --  statement 2
BBAR <= not B; --  statement 3
Z(2) <= not (A and BBAR and ENABLE); --  statement 4
ABAR <= not A; --  statement 5
Z(1 ) <= not (ABAR and B and ENABLE); --  statement 6
end dec_dataflgw;
```

**edit:**
I have updated the code, have checked it, this one works.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Concurrent statements are elaborated here into individual process statements with sensitivity lists comprised of the set of signals on the right hand side of each signal assignment statement. Delta cycles continue until the model is stable (no new signal updates are scheduled), then simulation time may advance, emulating concurrency. The number of delta cycles is determined by the longest chain of signal dependencies based on a process resumption order that is not defined by the VHDL standard, not portable and can vary by model complexity (e.g. port associations).

Comment: This just looks like **bad code**. Same thing as bad math expression, x = 1/2/3, is x = 1/(2/3) or (1/2)/3? We'll never know because it's **bad**. If you want to make sure your code does what you want it to do, write properly. Do you want to help Jack off the horse, or help jack off the horse? Right now I assume you want to jack off the horse.

Comment: sorry for this ,actually code i gave was just an example, i adopted it from pg 15 ftp://103.81.117.86/06%20Electronics%20and%20Communication%20Department/VLSI/VLSI_Ebook/J_Bhasker_VHDL.pdf   ,i was having trouble understanding that what value ABAR will hold in statement 6 ,when for very first time statement 6 is triggered and statement 5 has still never been triggered.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the same as

```
architecture dec_dataflgw of DECODER2x4 is
begin
   Z(3) <= not (A and B and ENABLE); --  statement 1
   Z(0) <= not (not A and not B and ENABLE); --  statement 2
   Z(2) <= not (A and not B and ENABLE); --  statement 4
   Z(1) <= not (not A and B and ENABLE); --  statement 6
end dec_dataflgw;
```

either way, you end up with:
[image: rtl]

> we don't have value for ABAR

You do have a value for `ABAR`. It is a signal which represents `not A`. And notice that the order of the lines in your code doesn't matter, since they are all concurrent. So `not A` can be substituted wherever you use `ABAR`.

I think you are confusing your concurrent assignments with synchronous clocked assignments. When you make assignments on a clock edge, their values are not utilized until the subsequent clock edge. Here you have no clock.

> will execution will go with initial(default) value of ABAR

Synthesized signals might not have default or initial values. You can make initializations for simulations (eg. `signal ABAR : BIT := '0'`), but the initialization may be ignored by the synthesis tool, depending on the technology. In general, you need to check your documentation to determine startup values, and whether initialization without resets are supported.

Answer (score 0):

> So, will execution proceed with an initial (default) value of ABAR
>   (default to the leftmost value ('left) of its declared type), or what?

Yes. During elaboration, signals which aren't otherwise initialised are given a default value as you describe. At the start of simulation, each of your concurrent statements will run through once, in an unknown order. The value that `ABAR` has at any particular delta will depend on this order (it may not be `not A`). Eventually, the network will stabilise when the delta cycles at time 0 have completed. The delta cycle mechanism allows you to ignore the fact that `ABAR` is not explicitly initialised.
Note taht this happens *before* you explicitly change anything (ie. set `B`, or whatever).